# How can I strip in-line comments from a text reader

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I'm trying to remove comments from within a text file by iterating through a streamreader and checking if each line starts with /*

```
    private void StripComments()
    {
        _list = new List<string>();
        using (_reader = new StreamReader(_path))
        {
            while ((_line = _reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var temp =_line.Trim();
                if (!temp.StartsWith(@"/*"))
                {
                    _list.Add(temp);
                }
            }            
        }
    }
```

I need to remove comments with the following format `/* I AM A COMMENT */` I thought that the file only had whole line comments but upon closer inspection there are comments located at the ends of some lines. The `.endswith(@"*/")` can't be used as this would remove the code preceding it.

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of text is this? In some texts, like C#, [you can have a line starting with `/*` that is actually significant](http://pastebin.com/AKMeDETc).

Comment: the endswith, or indexOf sure can help you identifying the lines with inline comment at the end , but then you have to run a small subroutine to remove only that comment (ie : doing a substring until the position of  the "start comment" character(s)

Comment: You should use a real source code parser here, because there are quite a lot of special cases you would need to consider.

Comment: So if the line is `text/*comment*/-comment-/*text` you want to keep `text-comment-/*text`? What if there is `//` inside?

Comment: I upvoted Tim's comment, but it was not correct. This line is parsed as a block comment (the // is ignored): /* comment // */

Comment: For my needs I only needed to remove the selection of characters that would make a /*sdfsdf*/ but thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable with regex

```
string pattern="(?s)/[*].*?[*]/";
var output=Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(path),pattern,"");
```

- `.` would match any character other then newline.
- `(?s)` toggles the single line mode in which `.` would also match newlines..
- `.*` would match 0 to many characters where `*` is a quantifier
- `.*?` would match lazily i.e it would match as less as possible

---

**NOTE**

That won't work if a string within `""` contain `/*`..You should use a parser instead!

Comment: I was a little unsure of the Regex syntax but this was exactly what I was after thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is a good fit for this.

```
string START = Regex.Escape("/*");
string END = Regex.Escape("*/");

string input = @"aaa/* bcd  
                de */ f";

var str = Regex.Replace(input, START + ".+?" + END, "",RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> _list = new List<string>();
Regex r = new Regex("/[*]");
string temp = @"sadf/*slkdj*/";
if (temp.StartsWith(@"/*")) { }
else if (temp.EndsWith(@"*/") && temp.Contains(@"/*"))
{
    string pre = temp.Substring(0, r.Match(temp).Index);
    _list.Add(pre);
}
else
{
    _list.Add(temp);
}
```